# Please explain cursor.execute in layman terms. Also,how to print the result of cursor.execute

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
 import mysql.connector as conn

 mydb = conn.connect(
 host="localhost",
 user="root",
 passwd="password",
 database="python_mysql"
 )

 mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

> ## To count the number of tables in database "python_mysql"
>
> ```
>   mycursor.execute("SELECT FOUND_ROWS();") #This contains 3 as result
> ```
>
> How to print the result as 3 by taking it in a new variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By fetching and assigning we can get the count

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT FOUND_ROWS();") 
data = mycursor.fetchall()
print(data[0][0]) # prints 3
```

Comment: data[0][0] will give 3

Comment: Yes thats the solution I have suggested